# symfony routing error after recipe upgrade

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

After upgrading symfony/framework-bundle recipe from 4.4 to 5.1 version i've got this error:

```
Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\PhpFileLoader, instance of Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\AnnotationFileLoader given, called in /app/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php on line 176
```

Recipe made this changes:
[image]
[image]

Also, i found if i remove PhpLoader typehint from constructor in `vendor/symfony/routing/Loader/Configurator/RoutingConfigurator.php`. everything starts work

Maybe i forget something? Or how could i make it works without changing vendor files?

symfony pacckages:

```
composer show --installed|grep symfony
You are using the deprecated option "installed". Only installed packages are shown by default now. The --all option can be used to show all packages.
symfony/asset                        v5.1.3  Symfony Asset Component
symfony/browser-kit                  v5.1.3  Symfony BrowserKit Component
symfony/cache                        v5.1.3  Symfony Cache component with PSR-6, PSR...
symfony/cache-contracts              v2.1.3  Generic abstractions related to caching
symfony/config                       v5.1.3  Symfony Config Component
symfony/console                      v5.1.3  Symfony Console Component
symfony/css-selector                 v5.1.3  Symfony CssSelector Component
symfony/debug-bundle                 v5.1.3  Symfony DebugBundle
symfony/debug-pack                   v1.0.8  A debug pack for Symfony projects
symfony/dependency-injection         v5.1.3  Symfony DependencyInjection Component
symfony/deprecation-contracts        v2.1.3  A generic function and convention to tr...
symfony/doctrine-bridge              v5.1.3  Symfony Doctrine Bridge
symfony/dom-crawler                  v5.1.3  Symfony DomCrawler Component
symfony/dotenv                       v5.1.3  Registers environment variables from a ...
symfony/error-handler                v5.1.3  Symfony ErrorHandler Component
symfony/event-dispatcher             v5.1.3  Symfony EventDispatcher Component
symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts   v2.1.3  Generic abstractions related to dispatc...
symfony/expression-language          v5.1.3  Symfony ExpressionLanguage Component
symfony/filesystem                   v5.1.3  Symfony Filesystem Component
symfony/finder                       v5.1.3  Symfony Finder Component
symfony/flex                         v1.9.1  Composer plugin for Symfony
symfony/form                         v5.1.3  Symfony Form Component
symfony/framework-bundle             v5.1.3  Symfony FrameworkBundle
symfony/http-client                  v5.1.3  Symfony HttpClient component
symfony/http-client-contracts        v2.1.3  Generic abstractions related to HTTP cl...
symfony/http-foundation              v5.1.3  Symfony HttpFoundation Component
symfony/http-kernel                  v5.1.3  Symfony HttpKernel Component
symfony/intl                         v5.1.3  A PHP replacement layer for the C intl ...
symfony/lock                         v5.1.3  Symfony Lock Component
symfony/mailer                       v5.1.3  Symfony Mailer Component
symfony/maker-bundle                 v1.20.0 Symfony Maker helps you create empty co...
symfony/mime                         v5.1.3  A library to manipulate MIME messages
symfony/monolog-bridge               v5.1.3  Symfony Monolog Bridge
symfony/monolog-bundle               v3.5.0  Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/options-resolver             v5.1.3  Symfony OptionsResolver Component
symfony/phpunit-bridge               v5.1.3  Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme       v1.18.1 Symfony polyfill for intl's grapheme_* ...
symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer     v1.18.1 Symfony polyfill for intl's Normalizer ...
symfony/polyfill-php80               v1.18.1 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 8...
symfony/process                      v5.1.3  Symfony Process Component
symfony/profiler-pack                v1.0.5  A pack for the Symfony web profiler
symfony/property-access              v5.1.3  Symfony PropertyAccess Component
symfony/property-info                v5.1.3  Symfony Property Info Component
symfony/proxy-manager-bridge         v5.1.3  Symfony ProxyManager Bridge
symfony/routing                      v5.1.3  Symfony Routing Component
symfony/security-bundle              v5.1.3  Symfony SecurityBundle
symfony/security-core                v5.1.3  Symfony Security Component - Core Library
symfony/security-csrf                v5.1.3  Symfony Security Component - CSRF Library
symfony/security-guard               v5.1.3  Symfony Security Component - Guard
symfony/security-http                v5.1.3  Symfony Security Component - HTTP Integ...
symfony/service-contracts            v2.1.3  Generic abstractions related to writing...
symfony/stopwatch                    v5.1.3  Symfony Stopwatch Component
symfony/string                       v5.1.3  Symfony String component
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle           v3.4.0  Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/templating                   v5.1.3  Symfony Templating Component
symfony/test-pack                    v1.0.6  A pack for functional and end-to-end te...
symfony/translation                  v5.1.3  Symfony Translation Component
symfony/translation-contracts        v2.1.3  Generic abstractions related to transla...
symfony/twig-bridge                  v5.1.3  Symfony Twig Bridge
symfony/twig-bundle                  v5.1.3  Symfony TwigBundle
symfony/validator                    v5.1.3  Symfony Validator Component
symfony/var-dumper                   v5.1.3  Symfony mechanism for exploring and dum...
symfony/var-exporter                 v5.1.3  A blend of var_export() + serialize() t...
symfony/web-profiler-bundle          v5.1.3  Symfony WebProfilerBundle
symfony/webpack-encore-bundle        v1.7.3  Integration with your Symfony app & Web...
symfony/yaml                         v5.1.3  Symfony Yaml Component
```

Comment: sooo ... did you update all symfony packages?

Comment: @Jakumi,  yes all packages are 5.1.* version

Comment: mh, somewhat out of ideas ... have you reinstalled libraries and cleared the cache (remove var/cache and vendor dir)?

Comment: @Jakumi Yes of course this is the first thing I did

Comment: the [MicroKernelTrait](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/753a0728e99f541bf51d873e91464fd657819f78/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php#L154) claims it provides a (Routing)PhpFileLoader - aliased - (used in L176 -> error message), but apparently it's not a (Routing)PhpFileLoader but an AnnotationFileLoader instead. Which I would assume shouldn't happen. I don't know what the resolve stuff does exactly, but something is going wrong...

Comment: @Jakumi i see, but can't find a problem, also can't reproduce it in empty project

Comment: not being able to reproduce the problem ... well ... is a problem. In that case I would say, you should move your code and configs to the empty project and see if it breaks ... it's probably some config stuff ... or maybe some caching that wasn't cleared with cache:clear etc.

Answer (score 0):

For workaround you should add this to your config:

```yaml
sensio_framework_extra:
    router:
        annotations: false
```

Fix was merged https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/38226